# Is there any way to parse value from this HTML code using XPath?

Tags: regex, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

So, I was trying to get some data out of this HTML code:

```
<span class="info-icon" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" title="" data-content="
    Рейтинг: <b>4.55/5</b><br/>

      Относительно остальных произведений: <b>3.58/5</b><br/>

    Всего голосов: <b>62</b>
" data-original-title="Информация о рейтинге">
      <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
    </span>
```

I was trying to get whole text using something like this:

```
//span[@class='info-icon']/@data-content
//span[@data-content='Рейтинг']
//span/@data-content
//span[@class='info-icon']/@data-content
```

I want to have an output like this:

```
4.55/5
3.58/5
62
```

Or atleast like this:

```
 Рейтинг: <b>4.55/5</b><br/>

 Относительно остальных произведений: <b>3.58/5</b><br/>

 Всего голосов: <b>62</b>
```

But I'm not getting anything.

P.s. Website URL can be any manga here: http://readmanga.me/
For example http://readmanga.me/tower_of_god

Comment: can you share the URL ?

Comment: Do note that `data-content` is an attribute and you are working with its string value, not mixed content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to scrape the source code directly like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "http://readmanga.me/tower_of_god"), 2000, 1), 
 "where Col1 matches 'Рейтинг:.*|.*остальных произведений:.*|Всего голосов:.*'", 0), 
 "[А-Яа-я<>br: ]", ), 
 "//$|/$", ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Is there any way to put values like this?
https://pasteboard.co/IpXGB8V.png

Comment: @ArturTretiak sure:  `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "http://readmanga.me/tower_of_god"), 2000, 1), 
 "where Col1 matches 'Рейтинг:.*|.*остальных произведений:.*|Всего голосов:.*'", 0), 
 "[А-Яа-я<>br: ]", ), 
 "//$|/$", )))`

Comment: Thanks, I got what I wanted.

Comment: At some pages they use "," as number divider instead of "."

How can i get this script to have full values if manga got that divider?

For example: they have "3,56" instead of "3.56"

Comment: @ArturTretiak use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "http://readmanga.me/drakuun__voshojdenie_princessy_drakonov"), 2000, 2), 
 "where Col1 matches 'Рейтинг:.*|.*произведений:.*|Всего голосов:.*'", 0), 
 "[А-Яа-я<>br: ]", ), 
 "//$|/$", )),,999^99))), " ", ".")))`

Answer (score 1):

The following xpath expressions should probably work:

```
tokenize(//span/@data-content,' ')[2]
```

selects

> 4.55/5

This one:

```
substring-before(tokenize(//span/@data-content,'<b>')[3],' ')
```

selects

> 3.58/5

and this one:

```
tokenize(//span/@data-content,'<b>')[4]
```

selects:

> 62

Comment: Imported XML cannot be parsed. (Was trying to add it into Google Sheets):
=importXML("http://readmanga.me/tower_of_god" , "tokenize(//span[@class='info-icon']/@data-content,' ')[2]")

Comment: @ArturTretiak - Sorry, I forgot that `tokenize()` is an xpath 2.0 function and Google Sheets supports only xpath 1.0 (same with Excel, I believe). I don't know of other ways of doing it :(